# Blocked from accessing an Iframe with origin 'null'

Tags: javascript, iframe

I am using an iframe for a pseudo-ajax file upload. The iframe is in the same view as the upload javascript:

```
<iframe id="upload_iframe" name="upload_iframe" style="position: absolute; left: -999em; top: -999em;"></iframe>
```

his works 'nicely' on my local machine, but when I deploy to an Azure web site, I get the following error in Chrome's debug console:

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to read the 'contentDocument' property
>   from 'HTMLIFrameElement': Blocked a frame with origin
>   "https://acme.azurewebsites.net" from accessing a frame with origin
>   "null".  The frame requesting access has a protocol of "https", the
>   frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match.

I understand this iframe to be same-origin, as it is strictly local, but how do I convince the browser that it is local? That is, is there something I should be doing to the origin and protocol of my iframe to avoid this error?

This is my code, in a nutshell:

```
dataAccess.submitAjaxPostFileRequest = function (completeFunction) {
    $("#userProfileForm").get(0).setAttribute("action", $.acme.resource.links.editProfilePictureUrl); 
    var hasUploaded = false;
    function uploadImageComplete() {
        if (hasUploaded === true) {
            return;
        }
        var responseObject = JSON.parse($("#upload_iframe").contents().find("pre")[0].innerText);
        completeFunction(responseObject);
        hasUploaded = true;
    }
    $("#upload_iframe").load(function() {
        uploadImageComplete();
    });
    $("#userProfileForm")[0].submit();
};
```

The form `userProfileForm` has its `target` property set to the iframe. This upload arrangement seems to work for most requests, and I don't know if the 'uncaught exception' message is just an observation on Chrome's part, or a potential show stopper. Is there not perhaps a way I can 'catch and ignore' such an exception, and just display a generic message if this happens?

Comment: Have you tried using a dummy URL on the same site for the IFRAME's `src` attribute? Example: `<iframe src='blank.html'></iframe>`. Or alternately injecting the IFRAME into the doc on demand instead of in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may depend on your browser, but the `IFRAME` element is generally not supported for the `data` protocol, see Wikipedia entry:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

It may have worked on localhost because localhost can use different authentication & authorization methods (for example on Windows it may run as a trusted site, and may pass your windows user credentials to server automatically, etc.). Same origin I believe means protocol, host, and port must all match. Since `data` protocol is different than `https` this is not same origin, hence the security error.

Usually the data protocol is only supported by these elements:

- object (images only) (ie: not activeX controls)
- img
- input type=image
- link
- CSS declarations that accept a URL

Can you post more of your code and problem statement? There are multiple other ways to accomplish file uploads. For example, traditional POST method (single file), HTML5 method (multi files), or even using javascript to send a stream of bytes to a web service (I did this once in an ActiveX control that used TWAIN to scan documents on user's computer and then upload the scanned image to the website).

Comment: Added my code. The iframe seems quite thin here, so I'm wondering e.g. what makes it assume the `data` protocol, or how to make it assume the `https` protocol. This is the only way I can get an 'ajaxy' file upload in IE9. I don't want to even start guessing what complications could arise if I wanted to try using ActiveX to stream the file.

Comment: Hopefully you solved this by now - somehow I missed the notification for your update. For IE7/8/9 I use a jQuery UI dialog that wraps an Iframe for file uploads, but the Iframe points to a web page that has the `<form><input type='file'/></form>` (psuedocode / details omitted). Also, I appreciate that you are still supporting IE9; most people on here dismiss this and suggest newer browsers, but for some reason many web developers fail to realize that business/industry is slow to adopt and often uses browsers that are several versions old.

Comment: I am no longer working on that project, but I somehow got it workng. I think it was when I returned a proper HTML document that wrapped the JSON, not just JSON. Ironically, the client was Microsoft SA that insisted on keeping compatibility as far back as IE9.